# Read a word from a file one character at a time then create a word from characters

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

So basically I have to take a command line argument which is a file and read the words one character at a time. I then have to take the characters and basically recreate those words into a variable that I can use to pass into a function I will use later on. I am having trouble trying to create the words I am adding the characters to an empty variable then printing it out but it just prints the characters out on a new line each time instead of the full word

UPDATE:: Code works, however it is printing basically a sentence I need it to print the words so I tried adding a new line statement but that does nothing

```
argc = len(sys.argv)

cmdlength = argc - 1

if cmdlength != 2:
    print ("Usage error, expected 2 args got " + str(cmdlength))
    exit()
else:
    word = ""
    with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fh: 
        while True:
            ch=fh.read(1)
            if not ch:
                #print("End of file")
                break
            word += ch
        print(word, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset `word` to just your last char in `word = "" + ch`, and print it in each loop.

Instead, just set it to the empty string once before the loop and each time you encounter a space, append to it in the loop, and print it after every space and once before exiting:

```
import sys

argc = len(sys.argv)

cmdlength = argc - 1

if cmdlength != 2:
    print ("Usage error, expected 2 args got " + str(cmdlength))
    exit()
else:
    word = ""  # Once before the loop
    with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fh: 
        while True:
            ch=fh.read(1)
            if not ch:
                print(word) # print the last word we were building before quitting
                print("End of file")
                break
            if ch == ' ':
                print(word)  # We got a space, let's print the word
                word = ''    # and reset it to the empty string
            else:
                word += ch  # we append the last char
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, however now I am receiving invalid syntax error with the line word = += ch, EDIT: Fixed it

Comment: The code technically works but it's not creating words its creating a sentence and I need it to create words to be passed into a function

Comment: My bad, I had updated your code and left the `=` behind, I edited it out. About your second comment: you should update your question and make that clearer. I'll update the code by supposing that you want to print a word on a new line each time you encounter a space.